# Select from select where Incremented column added

Tags: mysql

I have this query which creates a table/ladder of results and orders them in their finishing position. I'm now trying to break this down further and just get a particular username & their position from this query.

I thought just adding this query into a normal select would work but that doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

This creates the full results table with all the usernames and their position,

```
SELECT @r := @r+1 as Post , z.* FROM (
SELECT username, memid, SUM(CASE WHEN goals >= 0 THEN goals ELSE 0 END) AS Pos, SUM(CASE WHEN goals < 0 THEN -1*goals ELSE 0 END) AS Neg, SUM(goals) AS Diff 
FROM presults WHERE Week = 'Week 2' 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY Diff DESC, Pos DESC, memid asc )z, 
(SELECT @r:=0)y
```

I want to now single out one member,

ie:

```
SELECT username, Position FROM (
SELECT @r := @r+1 as Position , z.* FROM (
SELECT username, memid, SUM(CASE WHEN goals >= 0 THEN goals ELSE 0 END) AS Pos, SUM(CASE WHEN goals < 0 THEN -1*goals ELSE 0 END) AS Neg, SUM(goals) AS Diff 
FROM presults WHERE Week = 'Week 2' 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY Diff DESC, Pos DESC, memid asc )z, 
(SELECT @r:=0)y
) WHERE username = "John"
```

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias. Your second query is fine; just need to add an alias for the outermost derived table (subquery).

Comment: If you use MySQL 8, check out window functions, specifically `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, Position FROM (
SELECT @r := @r+1 as Position , z.* FROM (
SELECT username, memid, SUM(CASE WHEN goals >= 0 THEN goals ELSE 0 END) AS Pos, SUM(CASE WHEN goals < 0 THEN -1*goals ELSE 0 END) AS Neg, SUM(goals) AS Diff 
FROM presults WHERE Week = 'Week 2' 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY Diff DESC, Pos DESC, memid asc )z, 
(SELECT @r:=0)y
)T1 WHERE username = "John"
```